# kill Ubuntu 13.10 then install 14.04 fresh

Tags: upgrade

I am fed up trying to upgrade to 14.04

I have tried everything I can find from Ask and nothing is helping. Can I just kill it and install 14.04?
Or uninstall completely than boot up with a 14.04 disk?

Please dont make me go back to Gates!

Comment: Did you try the old-releases mirrors? And you can always install over 13.10 - no need to kill(?)/uninstall it.

Comment: @madscott Yes. See *step 8* of [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/152902/22949) to [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu): "*If you want to just clear out whatever is already on your hard disk, and use all of the space for Ubuntu, select that option, and skip to step 10.*" This works even if the space was previously used by a different Ubuntu system. (Of course you should offload any documents and other important files first!)

Answer (score 7):

1. Boot up the Ubuntu live-cd.
2. Open the Unity dash, and search Gparted. Run it.
3. Choose the drive that has your operating system on it from the list on the right-hand side.
4. Go to devices, and choose "create partition table". This will erase everything on the drive, so make sure to backup any of your data you want to keep.
5. Now on the desktop click on the Ubuntu installer icon, and proceed with the Ubuntu installation as normal. :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can just overwrite. Boot from the LiveCD and install Ubuntu 14.04 using the "Choose your Own" option. Make the EXT partition on your hard drive your `/` mountpoint, and make sure you check the Format check box.